# RADDropDownListElement does not contain a definition 'Owner'

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I use VS2013 and for Telerik WinControls.UI\v4.0_2015.1.331.40.
And I want to compile my application. And I get the following error message: **RADDropDownListElement does not contain a definition 'Owner'...**

What is changed is this component? And how do I resolve this?

The code is:

```
void SVDropDownList_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
            {
                if (sender is RadDropDownListElement && (sender as RadDropDownListElement).Owner is RadDropDownList)
                {
                    /* Alleen SelectedValue op null zetten werkt niet altijd */
                    ClearItem();
                    //((sender as RadDropDownListElement).Owner as RadDropDownList).SelectedValue = null;
                }
            }
            else if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
            {
                if (sender is RadDropDownListElement && (sender as RadDropDownListElement).Owner is RadDropDownList)
                {
                    string text = ((sender as RadDropDownListElement).Owner as RadDropDownList).Text;

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
                        Clipboard.SetText(text);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why not check the teleriks API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can access the control:

```
(sender as RadDropDownListElement).ElementTree.Control
```